# cypress how to test data-state is visble

Tags: automation, cypress

Here is the scenario:

I click a button and a popup comes and I want to test when I click on button, the popup should be visible

Sample code:

```
<button id='bt'>
<div id ='new_div' data-state = visible >

cy.get('#bt').click() 
//after clicking this I need to test data-state of "new_div" is visible/not
cy.get('#new_div').should('have.data-state','visible') //something like this
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

`cy.get('[data-state = visible]').should('be.exist')`

It will basically check if this tag `data-state = visible` present or exist inside your DOM at the moment when the popup is visible. 
But the best way, of course, is to grab selector from the opened popup!